# How to set hwaddr in docker 0.9.x

Tags: docker

i was using -lxc-conf="lxc.network.hwaddr=00:21:6a:81:17:d6" to specify the MAC address that the container should use.

From 0.9 it stopped working... any idea if there is any other way to accomplish this in 0.9?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before 0.9, Docker was using LXC as "backend driver", that allowed almost any raw LXC option to be passed as-is.

The [0.9 release](http://blog.docker.io/2014/03/docker-0-9-introducing-execution-drivers-and-libcontainer/) includes an [internal implementation](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/tree/master/pkg/libcontainer) of Cgroups and namespaces, Docker thus skips the LXC layer to "talk" directly with the low-level containerization tools.

I don't know yet how to pass advanced options to this internal implementation/driver (libcontainer), but you can tell Docker to keep using LXC (still supported) using the following startup option:

```
    docker --daemon=true -e lxc
```

You could check if your distribution has a **/etc/defaults/docker** configuration file where you could add this `-e` parameter and then restart docker (`service docker restart`)

Comment: docker -e lxc run -t -i --lxc-conf="lxc.network.hwaddr=00:21:6a:81:17:d6" ubuntu /bin/sh should work? it gives the error lxc.network.hwaddr = 00:21:6a:81:17:d6 is not supported by the native driver

Comment: Restart the daemon part of Docker with the `-e` option (server-side) instead of putting it with the container creation/run command (client side)